# Iterating Over Multidimensional Arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, iterator

I'm going over iteration within multidimensional arrays in Ruby on Codecademy and came across a question I can't seem to find the answer to. So, in their example, they show that a multidimensional array can be iterated using the following code:

```
things = [[1,2,3], ["red", "blue"]]

things.each do |sub_array|
    sub_array.each do |item|
      puts item
    end
end
```

This prints out the values of both sub_arrays. However, if I only want to display one sub_array, how would I go about that? I have tried the following code but I'm getting an undefined method `each' for 2:Fixnum error.

```
things = [[1,2,3], ["red", "blue"]]
    things.each do |numbers, colors|
      colors.each { |item| puts item }
    end
```

So, I guess my question is why my code is not functioning correctly and how I would go about printing out only the array at index 1?

Comment: First select the subarray you want to print, then print it.  If, for example, you wanted to print the colors array, `things[1] => ["red", "blue"]` (or `things.last`), then print `things[1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your block parameters deconstruct the array as follows:

The enumerator generated by `:each` yields each element of the outer array in sequence, and then applies the pattern matching based on the structure of the block parameters. So in the first iteration, you have `[1,2,3]` yielded to the block, which is then mapped to `numbers = 1` and `colors = 2`. `3` is ignored because it doesn't fit the pattern.

If you only want to display one sub-array, you don't need iterate over the whole array- just grab the required element by the index (if you know what the index is):

```
things[1].each {|color| ... }
```

Or, you can assign it to a variable in a similar way. As long as you know the colors will always be in the second position, you can do this:

```
_, colors = *things
colors.each {|color| ... }
```